Nativescript issue: You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders. when try to do `ns build android`
ns build android is throwing below issue. How to know which loader needs to be added here. Please help to resolve this issue.
ERROR in . / node_modules / glob / node_modules / minimatch / dist / mjs / ast.js 188: 11 Module parse failed: Unexpected token(188: 11) File was processed with these loaders: * . / node_modules / @nativescript / webpack / dist / loaders / nativescript - worker - loader / index.js You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders. |
return c; |
}


static #parseAST(str, ast, pos, opt) {
|
let escaping = false; |
let inBrace = false;
@. / node_modules / glob / node_modules / minimatch / dist / mjs / index.js 3: 0 - 31 823: 19 - 31 987: 0 - 31 987: 0 - 31 991: 16 - 19 @. / node_modules / glob / dist / cjs / src / index.js 4: 20 - 62 42: 18 - 60 @. / node_modules / glob - stream / index.js 7: 11 - 26 @. / node_modules / vinyl - fs / lib / src / index.js 5: 9 - 31 @. / node_modules / vinyl - fs / index.js 4: 7 - 27 @. / node_modules / module / dist / index.js 23: 15 - 34 @. / node_modules / mockery / mockery.js 37: 8 - 25 @. / app / applications / test - helpers / nativescript - mocks.js 4: 16 - 34 @. / app / sync.(xml % 7 Cjs % 7 C( ? < % 21\ .d.) ts % 7 Cs ? css) $. / applications / test - helpers / nativescript - mocks.js @. / node_modules / @nativescript / webpack / dist / stubs / virtual - entry - typescript.js 3: 16 - 103
issue image
==============================================================
tns doctor
√ Getting environment information
No issues were detected.
√ Your ANDROID_HOME environment variable is set and points to correct directory.
√ Your adb from the Android SDK is correctly installed.
√ The Android SDK is installed.
√ A compatible Android SDK for compilation is found.
√ Javac is installed and is configured properly.
√ The Java Development Kit (JDK) is installed and is configured properly.
√ Local builds for iOS can be executed only on a macOS system. To build for iOS on a different operating system, you can use the NativeScript cloud infrastructure.
√ Getting NativeScript components versions information...
√ Component nativescript has 8.7.0 version and is up to date.
‼ Update available for component @nativescript/core. Your current version is 8.3.6 and the latest available version is 8.7.2.
× Component @nativescript/ios is not installed.
‼ Update available for component @nativescript/android. Your current version is 8.5.0 and the latest available version is 8.7.0.
=====================================================
Webpack details from package.json
"@nativescript/webpack": "5.0.16", "webpack": "5.88.1", "webpack-cli": "5.1.4", "webpack-sources": "3.2.3"
I tried to add this loader "import-glob-loader": "^1.1.0". But there was no change.
